# DateTime to end of the day C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I receive a date like 1.01.2022 h:00, m:00, s:00, ms: 00

What is the best approach to get the date at the end of the day, something like: 01.01.2022 h:23, m:59, s:59, ms: 999?

I tried those 2 ways:

`var endOfDay = new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59, 999);`
 `time = time.Add(endOfDay);`

and

`time = time.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);`

Comment: I take the second route, mostly because I find it more readable. But neither are universally best. Perhaps you should explain what your criteria for best is.

Comment: What do you need this value for? What does calculating the value of the time at the end of the day have to do with how you are receiving a string representation of a date and time?

Comment: I have a date picker from dateFrom to dateTo and for dateTo I want to set time to end of the day for the case when user select same days for dateFrom and dateTo

Comment: What I usually do is ignore the time aspect completely. At the code block that actually performs the filtering I will add 1 day to the `dateTo` DateTime instance and then use a `less than` comparison. Example if the selected `dateTo` was `2022-01-31` then in the code that makes use of the value I will do `dateTo = dateTo.AddDays(1);` and `Where(x => x.EntityDate < dateTo)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This removes all doubt down to the resolution of a single tick. In the code below, assume that `dateAndTime` could include a non-zero time component.

```
dateAndTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

This

- ensures we are only working with a date that has no time component as our reference point/date
- moves us to the next date at midnight
- subtracts a single tick, bringing us back to our reference date with a full-resolution time component (you could do milliseconds if you prefer, just know it's less resolution).

While this works, it's generally better to consider an alternate design that doesn't rely on a time component at all (e.g. use a given date at midnight on the next day to act as a virtual end-of-day for the given reference date).

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to print out the range, the action format is opinion based. If you, however, want to check if some time is within or without the day, please do it as (note `>=` and `<`)

```
 if (timeOfQuestion >= day.Date && timeOfQuestion < day.Date.AddDays(1)) {
   ...
 }
```

Using onstructions like `endOfDays = time.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)` is dangerous:
please, note that `day.Date.AddMilliseconds(999.5)` - `double` value - should be *within* the day.